# What does "make [someone] into shoes" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In BBC's Sherlock series (Series 2 Episode 1, "A Scandal in Belgravia"),

> Jim Moriarty says to Irene Adler: *"If you have what you say you have, I'll make you rich. If you don't, I'll **make you into shoes**."*

What does he mean?

Googling led me to a [link](http://www.redbubble.com/people/sirwatson/works/8319533-moriartys-shoe-shop?p=kids-clothes) that that is probably enlightening, but unfortunately, not for me.

So if this is a play on words, then what are the possible meanings?

Comment: Related: [what-does-being-skinned-alive-mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58464/what-does-being-skinned-alive-mean-exactly-is-it-a-well-established-phrase)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expensive shoes are made from leather. Leather is tanned hide. Hide is skin. Making shoes from Adler is a threat/promise that Moriarty will skin her (i.e. remove her skin, probably while she is alive).

Comment: Note that Moriarty did not intend to literally skin Adler - he was using an ugly and suggestive metaphor.  He was using it to describe the pain (even death) he would inflict on her if she was lying.

Comment: @Daniel δ: What in the world makes you think that?  Pure, unbridled squeamishness?  We may also note that the "shoes" version is a just an expansion on his initial reaction, where skinning was specifically what was promised.

Comment: Even for a toughie, skinning wouldn't be the most efficient torture.  I should probably have included the word *necessarily*, but I can't edit my comment anymore.  I was mainly establishing the point that it wasn't necessarily literal, for the benefit of @ジョージ

Comment: @Matt : And what about this "Moriarty's Shoe Shop" ? I mean, are you aware of anything like that existing before the series -- or the T-shirt just was probably made up after the series?

Comment: @Daniel δ, I do not really like the way you've edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: @ジョージ What didn't you like?  I can change it back if necessary.

Comment: @ジョージ The Moriarty Shoe Shop is inspired directly by the line in the TV show. It would probably not exists if not for the TV show.

Comment: @Daniel δ: The benefit for a "toughie" in killing people who cross them in horrific ways isn't for the sake of torturing that person, it's *pour encourager les autres*.

Comment: Also Moriarty is truly insane (in the TV show where the line originates). I'll not spoil the ending, but really I think he would have shoes made of human skin if the fancy took him.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Damn right.  I don't know where this baseless conjecture that he's just kidding around when he says these things is coming from.

Comment: @chaos - indeed. Although I think Daniel's point was meant to be for a general threat rather than specifically for Moriarty's.

Comment: @Daniel δ: well, the title looks better. I take the rest as being slightly over-edited, but .. be my guest )

Answer (score 2):

It's not a play on words, but Moriaty is being playful here. The fun he's having is in the repetition and juxtaposition of the snowclone "If you X, I'll *make* you Y".

For purposes of threatening harm for being deceived he could just as easily have said "[...] I'll bake you into a pie", which in context with the preceding statement is a clumsy rhyme without the poetic juxtaposition.

While the literal meaning can be taken as to skin alive, I suspect Moriaty is being metaphorical here.